# Strongswan not working with wifi in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, hotspot, strongswan

Working on Ubuntu Linux. I have build the latest version of `strongSwan` from scratch.

But somehow I can't connect to a VPN using my hotspot.

What I want to know is, how do I tunnel the wifi through the ikev2 vpn tunnel, because wifi works only when vpn is down. It is a linux ipsec strongswan ikev2 client i am using, how can i get wifi working at the same time with vpn up tunneled through the vpn and not public ip?

Comment: Better post your question at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions)

Comment: Also, please provide much details as how you build the `strongSwan` and how you tried to connect VPN with wifi hotspot. You need to be more verbose to get your problem solved.

Comment: `./configure --enable-openssl --disable-ikev1 --enable-eap-identity --enable-eap-mschapv2
 ` is the last known to me configuration of it, it takes alot of searching on the net by copy paste in search the problem with the configuration found until all the libraries and stuff are installed for it, you need gmp 3 dev lzo and others im sorry i can't compile a list of instructions, what the wifi does when the vpn is connected is do the same with the stock repository strongswan does, that it cuts the vpn connection either with network manager or create_ap.... works fine no vpn I'm stumped

Comment: might or might not have to use --enable-eap-peap not sure it is an ikev2 connection. you just keep trial and error until the ./configure completes....... and you can connect, but as far as wifi same as stock repository strongswan build. its funny how there is no information for it yet, and people need to simplify it.

Comment: you also may be forced to use the charon plugin loaded as well.....

Comment: That's too much for a comment, I suggest you edit the question and add whatever is last known to you.